# JavaScript Альтернатива document.write()

Tags: javascript

Вот код:

```html
<script>
  var arr = ['<p> 1</p> <img src="1.jpg">', '<p>2</p> <img src="2.jpg">', '<p>3</p>  <
      img src = "3.jpg" >
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
      document.write(arr[r]);
</script>
```

Подскажите на что можно заменить `document.write()` что бы нормально отображались картинки

Comment: а кроме document.write ничего больше не смущает? например ошибки в объявлении массива, отсутствии закрывающих кавычек и переходах строки в строках

Answer (score 2):

Есть альтернатива, использовать .innerHTML

В примере кода это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
 var arr = ['<p> 1</p> <img src="1.jpg">', '<p>2</p> <img src="2.jpg">', '<p>3</p>  <img src = "3.jpg" >'];
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
      var el = document.getElementById("content");
      el.innerHTML = arr[r];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/distortriver/a4c5jjh5/

Comment: Помогло, Спасибо!